# Pointers in C, Returning Extra Parameters in C

Tags: c, pointers

Here is a simplified C code of the problem I am working on. In the actual function I am passing a pointer as a parameter to have it be "returned" as something is already being returned by foo(). Why does this give a segmentation fault? How do I fix it?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* num_rows){  
  int row_scan;  
  printf("enter:\n ");  
  scanf("%d", &row_scan);  
  num_rows = &row_scan;   
}

int main(void) {  
  int *num_rows;  
  foo(num_rows);  
  printf("%d", *num_rows);
  return 0;  
}
```

Here is a link to the code online: https://repl.it/repls/SilentFreshProperties#main.c

Comment: `row_scan` is a local variable. It is no longer valid after the function exits. Use dynamic memory allocation instead using `malloc`. Don't forget to `free` the memory.

Comment: `num_rows` is also a local variable in `foo`. So changing it does not change the caller's value. Need to pass in a double pointer for `num_rows`. `void foo(int **num_rows) { *num_rows = .. }` and call with `foo(&num_rows);`

Comment: The idea is more likely to `malloc` in `main`, pass pointer to `foo` and then assign the value by dereferencing the pointer inside `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you return pointer to the variable which stops to exists when function returns. This is wrong and it is called an Undefined Behaviour

You need to change your logic - pass the reserence to the variable defined in the calling function (in your case `main`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int* num_rows){  
  int row_scan;  
  printf("enter:\n ");  
  scanf("%d", &row_scan);  
  *num_rows = row_scan;   
}

int main(void) {  
  int num_rows;  
  foo(&num_rows);  
  printf("%d", num_rows);
  return 0;  
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xxo4Pr

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of your segfault is that `num_rows` in `main` is not actually being updated to point to anything meaningful.

The `num_rows` parameter in `foo` is a *different object* than the `num_rows` variable in `main`.  When you write

```
num_rows = &row_scan;
```

this does *not* affect the `num_rows` variable in `main` - it only affects the formal argument, which is local to `foo` and ceases to exist when `foo` exits.  So when you write

```
int main(void) {  
  int *num_rows;            // contains an *indeterminate* value
  foo(num_rows);            // does not update num_rows
  printf("%d", *num_rows);  // dereferencing that indeterminate value
  return 0;  
}
```

`num_rows` starts out with an *indeterminate* value that may or may not correspond to a writable memory address.  It is *not* updated by the call to `foo`, and
attempting to dereference that invalid pointer value leads to a segfault.

So how do you fix this?  Well, you start by declaring `num_rows` as an `int`, not an `int *`, and you pass the *address* of `num_rows` to `foo`:

```
int main(void) {  
  int num_rows;            
  foo(&num_rows);            
  printf("%d", num_rows);  
  return 0;  
}
```

Look at the `scanf` call in your `foo` function, you're basically doing the exact same thing - you define an object that will store the integer value, and you pass the *address* of that object to the function so that the function can update it.

You will need to make the following changes to `foo`:

```
void foo(int* num_rows){  
  int row_scan;  
  printf("enter:\n ");  
  scanf("%d", &row_scan);  
  *num_rows = row_scan;   
}
```

Instead of writing the address of `row_scan` to `num_rows` (which will be *invalid* once the function returns), you write the *value* of `row_scan` to `*num_rows`, which is the `int` object that `num_rows` *points to*.

You *could* dispense with the `row_scan` variable altogether and just write

```
scanf( "%d", num_rows ); // no &, num_rows is already a pointer
```

but, if you want to do additional validation, then it's a good idea to write to a local variable and not update `num_rows` unless you know the input is good, like:

```
int items_read = scanf( "%d", &row_scan );
if ( items_read == 1 )
{
  *num_rows = row_scan;
}
else if ( items_read == 0 )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Input was not an integer value, num_rows not updated\n" );
}
else
{
  fprintf( sterr, "EOF or error on input stream\n" );
}
```